# Objective-c get greatest from two NSIntegers

Tags: ios, objective-c

Now i am getting greatest `NSInteger` by suing `MAX()` example

```
NSInteger x = 10;
NSInteger y = 15;
NSInteger max = MAX(x,y);
```

But i am interested in why this function only used for `int` values mainly? And if it is correct to use `MAX()` for NSIntegers?

Comment: Check how NSInteger is implemented in objc.

Comment: @evnaz i set question to know it is valid yo use MAX for NSIntegers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MAX()` macro can be used for any two types which can be compared using `<` (less-than).  For C numeric types, the usual rules involving promotion and conversion of type will apply.

Short answer: `MAX()` works fine for NSIntegers.